Pass colors properly to manual scale in ggplot2 with multiple layers
I have a relatively complex ggplot2 plot with different layers: geom_line, geom_segment, geom_point and geom_text...
This is my MWE:
myseq <- "ACGTCAGTCGTAGCTAGCTAGCTGCATTATCGATCGATCGATCGA"
basecolors <- c("green","blue","black","red","magenta","grey")
aacolors <- c("#E60A0A","#E6E600","#145AFF","#FA9600","#3232AA","#00DCDC","#EBEBEB","#0F820F","#C8C8C8","#B45AB4","#8282D2","#DC9682","#BEA06E")
set.seed(123)
xlabels <- unlist(strsplit(myseq, ""))
xbreaks <- 1:length(xlabels)
trace_df <- data.frame(time=xbreaks,
                       A=rnorm(length(xlabels), mean=10, sd=2),
                       C=rnorm(length(xlabels), mean=5, sd=1),
                       G=rnorm(length(xlabels), mean=3, sd=1),
                       T=rnorm(length(xlabels), mean=8, sd=3),
                       call=xlabels)
xcolors <- ifelse(xlabels=="A", basecolors[1],
                  ifelse(xlabels=="C", basecolors[2],
                         ifelse(xlabels=="G", basecolors[3],
                                ifelse(xlabels=="T", basecolors[4],
                                       ifelse(xlabels=="X", basecolors[5], basecolors[6])))))
trace_df <- as.data.frame(tidyr::pivot_longer(trace_df, c(A,C,G,T), names_to="base", values_to="signal"))
#
cdr3_aa <- "VWXYZ"
cdr3_st2 <- 7
cdr3_en2 <- 22
cdr3_call <- unlist(strsplit(cdr3_aa, ""))
cdr3_mat <- t(matrix(c("VEE","WEE","XEE","YEE","ZEE","#E60A0A","#E6E600","#145AFF","#FA9600","#0F820F","white","black","white","black","white"), ncol=3))
df_arrows <- data.frame(x=seq(cdr3_st2, cdr3_en2-3, 3) -0.5, xend=seq(cdr3_st2+3, cdr3_en2, 3) -0.5,
                        y=18, yend=18, label=cdr3_mat[1,], color=cdr3_mat[2,], text=cdr3_mat[3,])
##
P <- ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::annotate("rect", xmin=xbreaks[cdr3_st2]-0.5, xmax=xbreaks[cdr3_en2]-0.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="grey", alpha=0.25) +
  ggplot2::geom_vline(data=df_arrows[-1,], ggplot2::aes(xintercept=x), color="grey", linetype=2, linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(data=trace_df, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=signal, group=base, colour=base), linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c(basecolors,aacolors)) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks, labels=xlabels, expand=c(0,1),
                              sec.axis=ggplot2::sec_axis(~., breaks=xbreaks, labels=xbreaks)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,20)) +
  ggplot2::geom_segment(data=df_arrows, ggplot2::aes(x=x, xend=xend, y=y, yend=yend, color=color), linewidth=8) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data=df_arrows, ggplot2::aes(x=xend, y=y, color=color), shape=18, size=8) +
  ggplot2::geom_text(data=df_arrows, ggplot2::aes(x=(x+xend)/2, y=y, label=label, color=text), fontface="bold") +
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x=ggtext::element_markdown(face="bold", size=12, color=xcolors),
                 axis.text.x.top=ggplot2::element_text(size=10, color="grey", angle=45, hjust=0),
                 axis.text.y=ggplot2::element_text(size=12),
                 axis.title=ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor.x=ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor.y=ggplot2::element_line(linetype=2),
                 legend.position="none")
grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=3, width=10)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()

At first I was passing just basecolors to scale_color_manual, but I got the error:

Insufficient values in manual scale

Now every combination I try for the colors there, messes up everything. I would need the colors of the lines in the plot to be the same colors as the letters in the x-axis (these are correct), and the colors of the segments and their text to be as specified in df_arrows...
Currently the above code produces this instead:

How should I pass the different color schemes properly? Thanks

I don't care for all these ggplot::. They make your code difficult to read. I suggest you (always) specify the breaks in scale_color_manual. That ensures proper mapping. One issue apears to be that there are more breaks than values ...

As you already have columns containing the colors for the segments, points and the labels in the df_arrows dataframe a quick fix would be to wrap in I() aka AsIs in the mapping (note: this requires ggplot2 >= 3.5.0). Doing so the "categories" are interpreted as colors (similar to scale_color/fill_identity) and do not require to add them to the manual scale.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  annotate("rect",
    xmin = xbreaks[cdr3_st2] - 0.5, xmax = xbreaks[cdr3_en2] - 0.5,
    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "grey", alpha = 0.25
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    data = df_arrows[-1, ], aes(xintercept = x),
    color = "grey", linetype = 2, linewidth = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = trace_df, aes(x = time, y = signal, group = base, colour = base),
    linewidth = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = basecolors) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = xbreaks, labels = xlabels, expand = c(0, 1),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., breaks = xbreaks, labels = xbreaks)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20)) +
  geom_segment(
    data = df_arrows, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend, color = I(color)),
    linewidth = 8
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = df_arrows, aes(x = xend, y = y, color = I(color)),
    shape = 18, size = 8
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_arrows, aes(x = (x + xend) / 2, y = y, label = label, color = I(text)),
    fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(face = "bold", size = 12, color = xcolors),
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(size = 10, color = "grey", angle = 45, hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(linetype = 2),
    legend.position = "none"
  )



You have 4 lines (A,C,G,T), so to override the default color scheme in scale_color_manual, you must specify 4 colours for the "values" argument.
Your problem is that you have 5 colours in df_arrow, which have different colours.
Currently, ggplot alone doesn't allow two different colour schemes for two different layers. However, the ggnewscales package allows you to have multiple color/fill scales.
basecolors <- c("green","blue","black","red")

library(ggnewscale)

ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::annotate("rect", xmin=xbreaks[cdr3_st2]-0.5, xmax=xbreaks[cdr3_en2]-0.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="grey", alpha=0.25) +
  ggplot2::geom_vline(data=df_arrows[-1,], ggplot2::aes(xintercept=x), color="grey", linetype=2, linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(data=trace_df, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=signal, group=base, colour=base), linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=basecolors) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks, labels=xlabels, expand=c(0,1),
                              sec.axis=ggplot2::sec_axis(~., breaks=xbreaks, labels=xbreaks)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,20)) +
  
  # Add this line
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  
  ggplot2::geom_segment(data=df_arrows, aes(x=x, xend=xend, y=y, yend=yend, color=label), linewidth=8) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data=df_arrows, aes(x=xend, y=y, color=label), shape=18, size=8) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c('#E60A0A','#E6E600','#145AFF','#FA9600','#0F820F')) +
  
  # Add this line
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  
  ggplot2::geom_text(data=df_arrows, aes(x=(x+xend)/2, y=y, label=label, color=label), fontface="bold") +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c("white","black","white","black","white")) +
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x=ggtext::element_markdown(face="bold", size=12, color=xcolors),
                 axis.text.x.top=ggplot2::element_text(size=10, color="grey", angle=45, hjust=0),
                 axis.text.y=ggplot2::element_text(size=12),
                 axis.title=ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor.x=ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor.y=ggplot2::element_line(linetype=2),
                 legend.position="none")



